# Cache efficient management of items in a QGraphicsScene

Tags: c++, qt, data-structures, model, qgraphicsscene

I have a `QGraphicsScene` which displays custom objects that inherit from `QGraphicsItem`. As an example, I want to display triangles that are made up like this:

```
struct Triangle {
    Point a;
    Point b;
    Point c;
};
```

The `QGraphicsItem` would look something like this:

```
class TriangleItem : public QGraphicsItem {
  public:
    Triange(QGraphicsItem* parent = 0);
    ...
  private:
    IndexTo _triangle;
};
```

However, I don't want to store the triangles within the QGraphicsItem directly, but rather in a `std::vector` or some other contigious data structure and keep them in a centralized place. There reason for this is, that I will have a bunch of algorithms performing transformations on these triangles. Since there are many of these triangles, my algorithms should be cache efficient and the datastructure should be easily iterateable.

The `QGraphicsItems` or the `QGraphicsScene` would then need hold a pointer/index to the triangles in this model. The `Triangles` in the scene are dynamic and can be moved/added/deleted (with the standard qt flags `ItemIsSelectable`, `ItemIsMoveable`). The problem is that a pointer into a `std::vector` is not guaranteed to stay valid.

I think it might be awkward to make the `QGraphicsScene` into an `QAbstractItemView`, so I am thinking about making my own model. However I am not quite sure on how to store the triangles internally and how to keep the model and the scene synchronized. How would you do this?

Comment: You can easy iterate over items using items(). QGraphicsScene stores items in bsp tree, so it not a simple vector. Probably you should implement your own scene. Also you can manually sync your vector with scene.